# How to check entries in a column for patterns and calculate the number of patterns?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a DataFrame:

```
         Name         Price
0        Dictionary     3
1        Book           4
2        Dict En-Ru     2
3        BookforKids    6
4        Dict FR-CHN    1
```

I need a piece of code that will check the column 'Name' for patterns that I can specify myself and will count the number of founded patterns in another DataFrame.

For instance, check the number of entries in the 'Name' column with the patterns Dict an Book ignoring the case should give this result:

```
|  Pattern    | Occurencies |
| ----------- | ----------- |
| Dict        | 3           |
| Book        | 2           |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
patterns = ['Dict','Book']
df.Name.str.extract(rf"({'|'.join(patterns)})", expand=False).value_counts()

Dict    3
Book    2
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

You can make it case insensitive with the `flags` argument:

```
patterns_lower = '|'.join([s.lower() for s in patterns])
(df.Name.str.lower().str.extract(rf"({patterns_lower})", expand=False)
        .value_counts())
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @jez  ! expand wasn't in my mind :)

Comment: It works but it is case-sensitive, it shouldn't make any difference between 'book' and 'Book', how to change that?

Comment: It gives me two rows one with 'book' and another with 'Book', it should give only a row with a sum of all the cases, 'book' or 'bOok' or 'Book', I mean ignoring how the word is written

Answer (score 0):

You can define your pattern as a custom function:

```
# example
def get_pattern(txt):
   if 'Dict' in txt:
       return 'Dict'
   if 'Book' in txt:
       return 'Book'

   return np.nan
```

Then you apply in your dataframe and use value counts:

```
df['Pattern'] = df['Name'].apply(get_pattern)
df['Pattern'].value_counts()

Dict    3
Book    2
dtype: int64
```